# I can't add an icon to the executable in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I can't seem to add an icon to the exe file in QT. I already added it to the top left corner but when I add `RC_FILES = icon.ico` to my `.pro` file it gives me an error in the generated resource file. The error says `myapp_resource_res.o Error 1`. This is my .pro file:

```
    #-------------------------------------------------
          #
         # Project created by QtCreator 2017-07-18T13:42:18
      #
      #-------------------------------------------------

     QT       += core gui

        greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

       TARGET = MentalMath3
            TEMPLATE = app

         # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
  # any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
 # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
   # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
   DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

  # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
   # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain 
 version of Qt.
  #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the 
   APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0



 SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

  HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

  FORMS += \
  mainwindow.ui

  RC_ICONS = icon.ico
```

This is the generated resource.o file:

```
    #include <windows.h>

      IDI_ICON1 ICON    DISCARDABLE "C:\\Users\\abhi\\Desktop\\Mental 
      Math\\MentalMath3\\icon.ico"

     VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 0,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 0,0,0,0
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
    #ifdef _DEBUG
FILEFLAGS VS_FF_DEBUG
    #else
FILEFLAGS 0x0L
   #endif
FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32
FILETYPE VFT_DLL
FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "0.0.0.0\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MentalMath3.exe\0"
            VALUE "ProductName", "MentalMath3\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "0.0.0.0\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0409, 1200
    END
         END
     /* End of Version info */
```

Comment: Either you did a copy/paste mistake or this is even an error in you .pro file: Please, search for the line `version of Qt.` There is probably an unintended line break. (The same for next line and following.)

Comment: Regarding your .pro file. Is there a reason for the "La Ola" indentation? The qmake probably does ignore it but for my esthetic sense it's hard.

Comment: @Scheff do I search for it in the pro file or the resource file? The resource file is all in one line so there is no line break.

Comment: See my first comment: "error in you **.pro** file:" (Sorry for the typo. I meant: "error in you**r** .pro file:")

Comment: @Scheff there is a line break after this line: #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

Comment: @Scheff could it be because I have a space in the folder in which the project is in

Comment: It could be a "copy/paste mistake". Then, please, edit the question to show the .pro file like on your local disc.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when am developing my qt application, to solve the problem.

- first step :

  create a resource file named like your project for example my project is Qtapp so the resource file will be "Qtapp.rc" inside of it :

`#include <windows.h>
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "iconEXE.ico"`

- second step:

  return in you .pro file and add the resource file like this

  `RC_FILE = Qtapp.rc`

  and enjoye